# gdialog cannot output variable

Tags: bash, scripts, dialog

```
copied='cp -v *SNAPSHOT.jar /home/user/folder'
$copied
```

prints information about copied files

however

```
gdialog --title "done" --clear --yesno "done $copied" 15 60
```

shows command that was executed, so it shows

```
done cp -v *SNAPSHOT.jar /home/user/folder
```

How to make gdialog show information about copied files  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write

```
copied='cp -v *SNAPSHOT.jar /home/user/folder'
```

this is only a variable assignment, the command is executed when you write

```
$copied
```

that is equivalent to

```
cp -v *SNAPSHOT.jar /home/user/folder
```

If you want to capture the output of the command you should do

```
output=$(cp -v *SNAPSHOT.jar /home/user/folder)
```

this execute the `cp` command and put the stdout of the command in the variable `output`. Then you can use this variable to show the message in gdialog:

```
gdialog --title "done" --clear --yesno "done $output" 15 60
```

Comment: this also can be done by using ` instead of '